# jsPlumb setting state that endpoint connections not editable

Tags: jsplumb

this should be rather simple but I cannot find something useful in google.
I have an source and an endpoint already connected via a connection.
This connection should not be removed by the user under any circumstances!

Any feedback is highly apprciated.. thanks in advance!

```
var isLooperTargetSetting = {
    isTarget:true,
    maxConnections: 1
};

var isLooperSourceSetting = {
    isSource:true,
    maxConnections: 1
};

var tar = looperPlumb.addEndpoint(end, {
    anchors:["BottomCenter"]
}, isLooperTargetSetting);
tar.setEnabled(false);
var src = looperPlumb.addEndpoint(start, {
    anchors:["BottomCenter"]
}, isLooperSourceSetting);
src.setEnabled(false);
looperPlumb.connect({
   source:start,
   target:end
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, connections made with jsPlumb.connect will be detachable via the mouse. You can prevent this by either setting an appropriate default value:

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({ 
  ...
  ConnectionsDetachable:false
  ...
});
```

or by specifying it on the connect call like this:

```
jsPlumb.connect({ 
  source:"aThirdElement", 
  target:"yetAnotherElement",
  detachable:false
});
```